# How can I get more columns if I have using aggregate function with keyword group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables in database

tblcustomer:

1. cust id pk
2. fname
3. lname
4. city

tblsales

1. salesid  pk
2. productid foreign key
3. cid foreign key
4. saleprice
5. salesdate

tblproduct

1. productid pk
2. productname
3. recommandedprice
4. category

I want to solve this query:

Return the `Product Category` and the average `Sale Price` for those customers who have
purchased two or more products

I have tried this one: but there is error...

```
select 
    AVG(Salesprice) ,FirstName 
from tblProducts 
inner join tblSales  on tblProducts.tid = tblSales.ProductId 
inner join tblCustomers on tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblSales.CustomerID 
group by FirstName
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Sounds a LOT like homework to me. If this isn't homework I would suggest not "TBLing", or naming your table with the tbl prefix.

Comment: you say there is an error but you don't tell us what the error is. what error are you getting?

Comment: If you want the product category, you'll have to select the product category.

Comment: What is your expected results and your actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without knowing what your issue is or what the data looks like this is not going to be easy to answer... what I think you want (assuming the first part of your query is correct) is this...

```
SELECT 
    AVG(Salesprice) ,FirstName 
FROM tblProducts 
JOIN tblSales  on tblProducts.tid = tblSales.ProductId 
JOIN tblCustomers on tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblSales.CustomerID 
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT(cust_id) > 1
```

I added a HAVING clause that checks to see if there are more than one record by customer in the table.